# How to compare two Web Service Descriptions (wsdl)?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I builds a file `Service.dll` from a Web service for use. Now, i want to auto update file `Service.dll` for time Web service changed. Current, my approach is save WSDL that is used to describe web services into `Service.dll` resource then compare WSDL in this resource with WSDL i got direct from Web service, if they is different i will update file Service.dll.
This is my code C#:

```
 public ServiceInspector(Uri serviceLocation)
    {
        if (serviceLocation.Query == string.Empty)
        {
            UriBuilder uriB = new UriBuilder(serviceLocation);

            uriB.Query = "WSDL";

            serviceLocation = uriB.Uri;
        }

        _serviceLocation = serviceLocation;

        WebRequest wsdlWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(serviceLocation);
        Stream wsdlRequestStream = wsdlWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        //Get the ServiceDescription from the WSDL file
        ServiceDescription sd = ServiceDescription.Read(wsdlRequestStream);
        string wsdlPath = @"C:\Users\John\Downloads\Compressed\Core\TestApp\Ref\Service.wsdl";
        sd.Write(wsdlPath);

        string sdName = sd.Services[0].Name;

        ServiceDescriptionImporter sdImport = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
        sdImport.AddServiceDescription(sd, String.Empty, String.Empty);
        sdImport.ProtocolName = "Soap";
        sdImport.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

        CodeNamespace codeNameSpace = new CodeNamespace();
        CodeCompileUnit codeCompileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        codeCompileUnit.Namespaces.Add(codeNameSpace);

        ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warnings = sdImport.Import(codeNameSpace, codeCompileUnit);

        if (warnings == 0)
        {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider prov = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();

            prov.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNameSpace, stringWriter, new CodeGeneratorOptions());

            //Compile the assembly
            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[2] { "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Xml.dll" };
            CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);

            param.GenerateExecutable = false;
            param.GenerateInMemory = false;
            param.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
            param.WarningLevel = 4;
            //Embedd wsdl into Resources
            param.EmbeddedResources.Add(wsdlPath);
            param.OutputAssembly = @"C:\Users\John\Downloads\Compressed\Core\TestApp\Ref\Service.dll";

            CompilerResults results = new CompilerResults(new TempFileCollection());
            results = prov.CompileAssemblyFromDom(param, codeCompileUnit);

            Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
        }
    }
```

And method check wsdl changed:

```
 private static bool IsServiceChanged(Uri uri)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\John\Downloads\Compressed\Core\TestApp\Ref\Service.dll");
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Service.wsdl");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.Query))
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(uri);
            uriBuilder.Query = "WSDL";
            uri = uriBuilder.Uri;
        }

        System.Net.WebRequest wsdlWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);

        using (Stream wsdlRequestStream = wsdlWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(wsdlRequestStream))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string result2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.Compare(result, result2, StringComparison.Ordinal) != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Current,My method `IsServiceChanged(Uri uri)` always return `True`, because file wsdl written into file has change the sort order namespace . E.g:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"....
```

this is wsdl taken directly from Web service, then written into file, it will become:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Please give me a best solution for update this my Service.dll? Thanks for help me !

Comment: See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/01/28/equality-semantics-of-linq-to-xml-trees.aspx) article.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for your reply !